# ActiveRecord: get only one record using has_one at children from grandparent at some conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

For example I have three table named A B and C. A can have many B and B can have many C. At only one condition `A.example_condition = 1` then A will have only one B and B has only one C.

I want to get directly C from A from that case. So I try this:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :special_c -> {joins("INNER JOIN B ON B.id = C.b_id INNER JOIN A ON A.id = B.a_id")
          .where("A.example_condition = 1")}, class_name: "C"
end
```

But when I run this above query, ActiveRecord will automatically insert statement after where clause:

```
A.id = C.a_id
```

Obviously C table doesn't have column `a_id` (it is stored in B table). My question is: How can I improve above query for my purpose or some other better way for this problem.

thanks